# On scroll jank / jitters on absolute positioned div with dynamic top value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onscroll

I've been experimenting / learning jQuery and Javascript lately and on one project I have run into a problem. Everything is working fine except for the dirty jank when scrolling. Is there a better way to achieve the same effect of a fixed content area with scrolling backgrounds ? I've looked into jank solutions and I kind of understand why it's happening, I just can't quite get my head around fixing it and what to apply to my code. Any suggestions / solutions would be great !

The JS

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.block').each(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
            elementOffset = $(this).offset().top,
            distance = (scrollTop - elementOffset);
        $(this).children('.cntr').css("top", distance);
    });
});
```

Code pen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAGyVj

Of course it works fine in Codepen...

Try the iframe link directly in it's own tab you can see the jank I'm talking about - http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/bb57ff22b00020c4b4d07f0cf08718361476564202890/index.html

Comment: Your CodePen example is constantly reloading itself. Please ensure that when asking a question, a minimal, concrete and verifiable example is provided—not a broken one.

Comment: Instead of setting the `top` value on scroll, try setting `position: fixed;` with JS when it is needed. That will get rid of the jitter and also needs significantly less computing power. Here's a simple example that demonstrates this concept: https://jsfiddle.net/fabe/tjckfusk/

Comment: I started with position fixed when I first wanted to try out the scrolling background fixed text within a div container idea but I couldn't get it to work with pure css. That's why I went absolute so I could use the position relative / overflow hidden setup on the wrapper divs, if you know of any examples of the same effect on scroll please post them so I can see how it's been done before.

Comment: Try using the new [passive mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) for event listeners. I haven't tried to coax jQuery into doing this, but presumably it will be able to at some point if it can't yet.